# UnSupportedEntityException when trying to create/render records containing slug extension

Tags: orocommerce

I am trying to implement slugs in my bundle, but when i try to create a record and run my message consumer i get the following error:

```
Unexpected exception occurred during Direct URL generation ["exception" => Oro\Bundle\RedirectBundle\Exception\UnsupportedEntityException { …}] ["processor" => "Oro\Bundle\RedirectBundle\Async\DirectUrlProcessor","message_id" => "oro.6256de2124b630.96491198","message_body" => ["createRedirect" => true,"id" => [3],"class" => "Phpro\OroBundleBlogBundle\Entity\BlogPostCategory"],"message_properties" => ["oro.message_queue.client.topic_name" => "oro.redirect.generate_direct_url.entity","oro.message_queue.client.queue_name" => "oro.default","oro.security.token" => "organizationId=1;userId=1;userClass=Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User;roles=ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"],"message_headers" => ["content_type" => "application/json","message_id" => "oro.6256de2124b630.96491198","timestamp" => "1649860129","priority" => "2"],"elapsed_time" => "34 ms","memory_usage" => "107.57 MB"]
```

The slugs are stored, but the use of the **get_slug_urls_for_prototypes** twig filter results in the following error `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("").`  Again because of the **UnsupportedEntityException**

Am i missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [OroCommerce documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/bundles/commerce/RedirectBundle/) the entity must implement the interface to support slugs. Make sure you fulfilled this requirement.

Comment: I have implemented the SluggableInterface with the SluggableTrait. Everything seems to be fulfilled, but the same error keeps popping up.